# ASP.net, how can I access a remote machine and create a user account and create and share a folder

Tags: asp.net, share, remote-access, user-accounts, create-directory

I'm creating an ASP.net (C#) website and I need to achieve some interesting tasks like accessing a remote machine, creating a user account and creating and sharing a folder.

Please guide me with this?

Comment: Are you using Active Directory in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Powershell might be the solution given the range of tasks that you're looking to achieve

http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/
http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html

and in essence you'll be referencing the System.Management.Automation assembly, creating a powershell object, and executing dynamic scripts through it.

Comment: I'd recommend the WMI API for this. PowerShell is very specific and has a "UI feel" about it. You can do the same that PowerShell does under the covers via the WMI AMI, which is easier to use in code and it's designed to work with remote systems natively without any remoting features required.